# Wrong position of OnClick Dropdown Menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

Hello, this is the link before click. And when I click on that link, that link go to upper side of the page, like this;
[image]

You can see the difference. I am also attaching the code please check.

Here is what I am working on;

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
  var myDropdown = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    if (myDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
      myDropdown.classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.show {display: block;}
```

```html
<div class="header">
   <table border="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
     <td width="5%" valign="top"><img src="./images/logo_small.png" alt="" title=""></td>
     <td width="45%"><div class="web_title"><a href="index.php">ASHNAB</a></div></td>
     <td width="50%" align="right">
      <div class="header_links">
       <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Link Drop Down</a>
      </div>
      <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
       <a href="#home">Home</a>
       <a href="#about">About</a>
       <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </div>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </div>
```

I don't know where the issue lies.
Please help

Comment: Why are you using tables? Tables are intended for tabular data and not for design, tables gives more problems than solutions in this case. Take a look at some [dropdown examples](https://freefrontend.com/css-dropdown-menus/)

Comment: The dropdown takes room in the table cell, which means it moves the item up that's already in it. Avoiding tables is good, as @Triby wisely suggested. Beyond that, if you don't want other things to move when your dropdown appears, you'll need to handle things differently, probably by making giving the dropdown a position:absolute and other things related to that.

Comment: @Yishmeray, I am using table for a purpose. Is there any way so I could use drop down along with table?

Comment: Of course you're using tables for a purpose. Everybody has a purpose. Every act has a purpose. Triby wrote, and I agree (with some exceptions) - tables are for tabular data, and this is totally and completely and manifestly not tabular data. Sure, do what you want. Triby gave good advice.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a small thing, but there you go. Change only the CSS:

```css
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 2rem;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

The absolute positioning takes the element out of the normal flow. That's about it.